# Gyroscope and magnetic field sensor events in Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-sensors

How do I access the values of a magnetic field and gyroscope sensor event when accessing sensors natively on Android:

```
if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = event.acceleration.x;
            ...
    }
else if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE) {
        ???
    }
else if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        ???
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: the values are in the event.values[] array - it's all explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html

Comment: I don't think that's quite right. The ASensorEvent struct looks as follows: http://mobilepearls.com/labs/native-android-api/include/android/sensor.h

Comment: Ah! sorry, I drive them in java, if you're in C then they appear to be in the acceleration or magnetic union - which would make it event.magnetic.x or event.acceleration.azimuth - but they're all the same thing underneath

Comment: See, there is no field in the union for the gyroscope. And surely, the accelerometer doesn't give you angular measurements. Do you mean even.magnetic.azimuth? I'm just trying to figure out which field in the union corresponds to which sensor. I can't find documentation anywhere except for the accelerometer.

Comment: well I would just read out the first 3 floats and see if they make sense. Android documentation varies, it's got to be in there somewhere, so just have a rumage

Answer (score 3):

Have a look into the header file of the sensor:

> ANDROID-NDK-ROOT-DIR/platforms/android-/arch-arm/usr/include/android/sensor.h

```
typedef struct ASensorVector {
    union {
        float v[3];
        struct {
            float x;
            float y;
            float z;
        };
        struct {
            float azimuth;
            float pitch;
            float roll;
        };
    };
    int8_t status;
    uint8_t reserved[3];
} ASensorVector;

typedef struct ASensorEvent {
    int32_t version; /* sizeof(struct ASensorEvent) */
    int32_t sensor;
    int32_t type;
    int32_t reserved0;
    int64_t timestamp;
    union {
        float           data[16];
        ASensorVector   vector;
        ASensorVector   acceleration;
        ASensorVector   magnetic;
        float           temperature;
        float           distance;
        float           light;
        float           pressure;
    };
    int32_t reserved1[4];
} ASensorEvent;
```

By the way I found that example:

https://github.com/Uroc327Mirrors/pixellight/blob/43a661e762034054b47766d7e38d94baf22d2038/Base/PLInput/src/Backend/Android/AndroidSensorManagerDevice.cpp

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion you can get data of any event by the field data like:

```
if(event.type == ASENSOR_TYPE_GYROSCOPE) 
{
    float x=event.data[0];//Rate of rotation around the x axis
    float y=event.data[1];//Rate of rotation around the y axis
    float z=event.data[2];//Rate of rotation around the z axis
}
```